# Trouble with a C "for" Loop - Won't iterate past 1st

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, cs50

I am working on a problem for CS50 in which I must create a pyramid out of `#`'s based on user input of a height. Here is what I have so far, but for height of 8, it only iterates once. For height of 7, I get about four lines of just a mess of `#`'s.

```
//Create GetPosInt() function
int GetPosInt(void) {
    int n = GetInt();
    while (n <= 0) {
        printf("That won't work...\nRetry: ");
        n = GetInt();
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("How high should Mario's pyramid be?\nHeight: ");
    int h = GetPosInt();
    while (h > 23) {
        printf("Try something smaller!\nHeight: ");
        h = GetPosInt();
    } 
    char str[] = "##";
    char strad[] = "#";
    int l = h + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        printf("%*s\n", l, str);
        strcat(str, strad);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is my first attempt with the string.h library.
Please only tips on fixing my code - I'm certain there are other ways about it, but if it's possible this way, I'd like to keep it so for the class!

Comment: Take a look at the code inside the loop... Don't you do something that ends it inside? I think you do.

Comment: `char str[] = "##";` : Extra space does not exist that can be concatenated strings.

Comment: The array `str` is created to contain *three* characters: Two `'#'` characters and the string terminator. Appending to this will write *out of bounds* and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It would have been better if you showed us what output you are getting.

Comment: '       ##'  (total of seven spaces prior to the `#`'s)

Comment: `str` has no room for what you are trying to do with `strcat`.

Comment: Shtap with teh bean-counting and use sane buffers, eg [128]

Comment: @LPs I bet str has enough room.

Comment: @AnishSharma Well,  I very like to win easily... ;)

Comment: @LPs It worked with me. I am too a novice so i may ave been mistaken.

Comment: @AnishSharma Well, as Joachim wrote: it is _Undefined behavior_.

Comment: @AnishSharma try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(str));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `str` array/C-String has no room to concatenate other chars than 2 chars.

As a little change you could do:

```
char str[128] = "";
strcat(str, "##");
```

Comment: So `char str[] = "##"` only allows the string to have two characters? I thought that was directed by what went into the `[]`?

Comment: You're initializing it to three chars, two hashes and a nul.

Comment: Not defining a specific size demand to the compiler to give it the correct size based on the initializer you write. In your case size of str will be 3: 2 hashes and 1 null terminator.

Comment: This change did it. It was the issue of not having space to concatenate into the str variable, as was suggested. I incorrectly assumed it would grow as I concatenated to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return 0;` is inside the loop, hence why. Edit as so:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
      printf("%*s\n", l, str);
      strcat(str, strad);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Tried this, but I'm still only getting one iteration from different heights.

Answer (score 1):

In the C programming language you have to manage memory yourself. These memory allocations will not expand when you use strcat. Instead you will override memory beyond the memory allocated for str. I strongly suggest you first do an introduction into programming in C and how to manage memory manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should return after the loop. You are leaving the function as soon as the first iteration finishes.

Also you should try defining str as : 
    char * str;
    str = malloc( sizeof(char)* 2);
    str = strcat(str, "##");

And using strcat as :  str = strcat(str,strad);

Comment: Changed   
    char str[] = "##";
to  
    char * str = "##";  
and  
    char * str[] = "##";  
with no luck.

Comment: If you really need to start with those two you need first to allocate memory and then strcat those two ## . Try using Malloc() function to do this.

Comment: Im on mobile right now so the code is not being posted correctly. I hope thats not a problem.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: It's just to make things easier to understand. Not a huge fan of magic numbers.